# Can I deploy a Docker Image based in Rust to an Azure IoT Edge Device Module?

Tags: azure, docker, rust, azure-iot-edge

I'm working on developing an MQTT broker written in Rust, and I need to deploy it to Azure to run up there.  I have successfully built a Docker image of my code and everything seems to be functioning as intended.

Now I'm trying to take my Docker image and deploy it to a module inside of an Azure IoT Edge Device.  I was able to upload my Docker image to my Azure Container Registry.

My issues arise when I try to make a deployment configuration for my Edge Device.  Below is my `deployment.json` file

```
{
    "$schema-template": "4.0.0",
    "modulesContent": {
        "$edgeAgent": {
            "properties.desired": {
                "schemaVersion": "1.4",
                "runtime": {
                    "type": "docker",
                    "settings": {
                        "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
                        "loggingOptions": "",
                        "registryCredentials": {
                            "My-Container-Registry": {
                                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME",
                                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD",
                                "address": "<My-Container-Registry>.azurecr.io"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "systemModules": {
                    "edgeAgent": {
                        "type": "docker",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.4",
                            "createOptions": {}
                        }
                    },
                    "edgeHub": {
                        "type": "docker",
                        "status": "running",
                        "restartPolicy": "always",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.4",
                            "createOptions": {
                                "HostConfig": {
                                    "PortBindings": {
                                        "5671/tcp": [
                                            {
                                                "HostPort": "5671"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "8883/tcp": [
                                            {
                                                "HostPort": "8883"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "443/tcp": [
                                            {
                                                "HostPort": "443"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "modules": {
                    "BrokerModule": {
                        "version": "1.0",
                        "type": "docker",
                        "status": "running",
                        "restartPolicy": "always",
                        "settings": {
                            "image": "<My-Container-Registry>.azurecr.io/<my-image>:latest",
                            "createOptions": {
                                "Cmd": [
                                    "Eula=accept"
                                ],
                                "HostConfig": {
                                    "PortBindings": {
                                        "1883/tcp": [
                                            {
                                                "HostPort": "1883"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "env": {
                            "IP_ADDR": {
                                "value": "0.0.0.0"
                            },
                            "LOGGING_LEVEL": {
                                "value": "Debug"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "$edgeHub": {
            "properties.desired": {
                "schemaVersion": "1.4",
                "routes": {
                    "BrokerModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/BrokerModule/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
                },
                "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
                    "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much of it was auto generated, my only requirements for this deployment are that I need to be able to listen to the MQTT port of 1883 and those two environment variables my application uses to determine where to open the broker on and the minimum logging level to use.

Below are some screenshots showing the state of my Azure portal after I complete the deployment.

[Deployment Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCNm2.png)

[Device and Module Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRQxH.png)

[Troubleshooter Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCriJ.png)

I am also confused by the error codes of NA, but I am also unable to get logs from any of the modules from command line commands or the Azure Portal

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if any more information is needed I am happy to provide what I can.

If I am unable to do this using a Rust image, then are there other ways I can upload my image without having to rewrite my code in another language that would be supported in Azure?

I've tried making a `deployment.json` in both the Azure Portal and outside in Visual Studio using the Azure IoT Hub Tools extension.  Both looked similar but produced the same results.  I expect the modules to run and to be able to see network traffic in the MQTT protocol.  I have flows set up in Node-Red to send and receive messages.

### Update

After doing some digging in the logs, I've found that the edgeAgent and edgHub modules are both complaining because a parameter called 'uriString' is null. What exactly does this string need to contain. I've been using ChatGPT a bit to help, and it mentioned things like " IoT Hub endpoint, Docker registry, or any other service that the module is interacting with."

Comment: Since none of your modules are reported by the device, this would suggest that your Edge instance is having a problem starting up. A couple of commands that may help you determine the problem:
```sudo iotedge list``` will show you which, if any, modules Edge has started. ```sudo iotedge system status``` will show you any critical errors logged by the services. The fact that your module's application is written in Rust makes no difference to Edge.